# double versus long for large numbers in Java

Tags: java, integer, double, long-integer

I'm just starting to learn to code and this might be a very simple question but I have seen double used for numbers that are larger than int can hold. If I understand correctly, double is less precise than using long might be.

So if I have a number larger than int can hold, would it be best to use double or long? In what cases is one preferred over the other? What is best practice for this?

(Say I would like to store a variable with Earth's population. Is double or long preferred?)

Comment: Note that there are also `BigDecimal` and `BigInteger` types.

Comment: Personally, I would use long since earth population is going to be a whole number. You can use `BigInteger` or `BigDecimal` as well although they might be overkill.

Comment: `long` is for *precise integer values*, e.g. `1234567890123`; if value is larger the `MAX_VALUE` (~`1e19`) you'll have *integer overflow* (totally wrong value). `double` is for *approximate* values: up to (`2^53 - 1` ~ `1e16`) integer values are *exact*, but then they becomes *approximate* up to `~1e308` (no catastrophy integer overflow)

Comment: The big difference between `long` and `double` is that `long` can hold integer numbers only, while `double` is a floating-point number type (it can hold fractions). See: [Primitive Data Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

For population of humans, use `long` primitive or `Long` class.

## Details

The floating-point types [trade away accuracy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Accuracy_problems) in exchange for speed of execution. These types in Java include `float`/`Float` and `double`/`Double`.

| Size | Whole numbers | Fractional numbers |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 32-bit | `int` / `Integer` | `float` / `Float` |
| 64-bit | `long` / `Long` | `double` / `Double` |
| varies | `BigInteger` | `BigDecimal` |

If working with whole numbers (no fractions):

- For smaller numbers ranging from -2^31 to 2^31-1 (roughly plus or minus 2 billion , use `int`/`Integer`. Needs 32-bits for content.
- For larger numbers, use `long`/`Long`. Needs 64-bits for content.
- For extremely large numbers, use `BigInteger`.

If working with fractional numbers (not integers):

- For numbers between (2-2^-23) * 2^127 and 2^-149 where you do *not* care about accuracy, use `float`/[`Float`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Float.html). Needs 32-bits for content.
- For larger/smaller numbers where you do *not* care about accuracy, use `double`/`Double`. Needs 64-bits for content.
- For more extreme numbers, use `BigDecimal`.
- If you care about accuracy (such as money matters), use `BigDecimal`.

So for the earth’s population of humans, use `long`/`Long`.